# ¿Cómo podría hacer un div en forma de flecha al estar activa la opción?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Buen día.
Necesito hacer un div con forma de flecha en el margen derecho al estar activa dicha opción. Podrían darme una idea de comenzar de maquetarlo, y si estaría bien que utilice bootstrap 4, gracias.

Adjunto imagen referencial
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al avanzar, pasará a poner como activo el siguiente capitulo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hacer un triangulo con CSS es sencillo usando bordes. Pones las dimensiones en 0 y creas un borde transparente que sea del mismo tamaño de la flecha que quieres lograr. Luego colorea uno de los bordes y tienes una flecha como la que quieres. Los [pseudoelementos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudoelementos) son ideales para crear la punta de la flecha.

```css
.arrow-right {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.arrow-right.active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  /* esta es la parte importante */
  border: transparent solid 50px;
  border-left-color: red;
}

.arrow-left {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.arrow-left.active:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -99px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  /* esta es la parte importante */
  border: transparent solid 50px;
  border-right-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right">
  Texto menu izquierda
</div>
<br>
<div class="arrow-right active">
  Texto menu izquierda active
</div>
<br>
<div class="arrow-left">
  Texto menu derecha
</div>
<br>
<div class="arrow-left active">
  Texto menu derecha active
</div>
```

Realmente es muy sencillo de hacer así que puedes tener o no bootstrap incluido en la aplicación.

Incluí un texto para que se vea una vista previa porque como dices es un menú.

Comment: Gracias man, ¿Para la distribución del layout me recomiendas colocar un col-md-4 para el "sidebar" y un col-md-8 para el contenido?

Comment: Si. Un par de detalles, cuando el menú está inactivo tienes que agregarle un `margin` en la dirección de la flecha para que tu menú no cambie de tamaño cuando esté inactivo. Para centrar el texto verticalmente, si necesitas hacerlo multilinea como en la foto mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8865463/4015449) de StackOverflow. Yo usé la técnica más sencilla porque era un ejemplo simple.

Comment: @JoelSulcaCordova No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió

Answer (score 1):

Basandome en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34895520/4987172), adapté el código para que veas cómo varia el div basado en su clase active haciendo clic:

```js
$(".box").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #307084;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.box.active:before, .box.active:after {
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  content: "";
}
.box.active:before {
  top: 0px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left bottom, #307084 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #307084 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
}
.box.active:after {
  top: 50%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #307084 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #307084 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" style="font-size: 20px">
  css se adapta al tamaño del div
</div>

<div class="box" style="font-size: 25px;">
  css se adapta al tamaño del div
</div>

<div class="box active" style="font-size: 40px;">
  css se adapta al tamaño del div
</div>
```