# Como puedo hacerle una punta a un div con css

Tags: html, css

Como puedo hacer que el div "opcionesTransferencia" tenga una punta como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento tengo asi el html

```
<div id="descripcionTransferencia">
        <label>Transferencia bancaria directa</label>
        <br><br><div id="opcionesTransferencia">
            <p>Tienes dos opciones para realizar tu pago:</p>
            <p>1. Sinpe Móvil transferencia por billetera electrónica por medio del celular al número.<br>
                2. Transferencia a la cuenta</p>
            <p>Por favor, usa el número del pedido como referencia de pago.</p>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: right">
            <button class="text-white" type="submit">Realizar el pedido</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: intente lo que dice masomenos esta pregunta, pero no pude,https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/224204/c%C3%B3mo-podr%C3%ADa-hacer-un-div-en-forma-de-flecha-al-estar-activa-la-opci%C3%B3n

Comment: mira tutoriales de [::after CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Answer (score 0):

Al contenedor `angulo` se le agrega un `::before` de la siguiente manera:

```
.angulo::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: -40px;
    left: 5%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid var(--color);
    border-left: 20px solid transparent
}
```

Se ajusta jugando con los bordes, y los márgenes.

```css
:root {
--color: rgba(0,128,0, 0.3)
}

label {
font-weight: bold
}

#descripcionTransferencia {
width: 100%;
height: 300px
}

#opcionesTransferencia {
position: relative;
width: 100%
}

.angulo {
display: block;
position: relative;
padding: .50rem;
background-color: var(--color)
}

.angulo::before {
display: block;
content: "";
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: -40px;
left: 5%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 20px solid transparent;
border-right: 20px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 20px solid var(--color);
border-left: 20px solid transparent
}
```

```html
            
<div id="descripcionTransferencia">
        
        <label>Transferencia bancaria directa</label>
    <br><br>
        <div class="angulo" id="opcionesTransferencia">
        <p>Tienes dos opciones para realizar tu pago:</p>
        <p>1. Sinpe Móvil transferencia por billetera electrónica por medio del celular al número.<br>
            2. Transferencia a la cuenta</p>
        <p>Por favor, usa el número del pedido como referencia de pago.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: right">
        <button class="text-white" type="submit">Realizar el pedido</button>
    </div>
</div>
```